# Instability opening new page Protractor non angular site

Tags: javascript, windows, tabs, jasmine, protractor

I have a problem when I click in non angular site and the test opens a new non angular site tab.  Sometimes works (a lot of times), but sometimes shows the following error:

> Unknown Error: null value in entry: name=null

This is the code:

```
    browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;

    element(by.id('go')).click().then(function () {

       browser.driver.getAllWindowHandles().then(function (handles) {
           browser.driver.switchTo().window(handles[1]).then(function () {
             browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(element(by.id('text'))), 15000);    
             expect(element(by.id('text')).getText()).toEqual('Works');
             expect(element(by.css('#crumbsNav .last')).getText()).toEqual('Payment');
         });
         browser.driver.close();
         browser.driver.switchTo().window(handles[0]);
    });
```

How I can fix it?

Comment: Did you try to wait until the new tab is opened before performing operations on it? This way - `element(by.id('go')).click().then(function(){//Your code to switch to new tab});`. Also wait until elements are loaded on new page using `wait()` function. Thanks

Comment: @Girish Sortur Yes, I also tested that way. In fact, I'll edit the code to display all the ways that I've tried.

Answer (score 0):

> UnknownError: null value in entry: name=null

Means you are trying to switch to a window that is not opened at the moment.
you should wait for the number of tabs to be more than 1 and only then switch.

So:

```
browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;

element(by.id('go')).click().then(function () {

   browser.driver.getAllWindowHandles().then(function (handles) {

       browser.wait(function(){return handles.size() > 1}, 15000);//MY ADDITION

       browser.driver.switchTo().window(handles[1]).then(function () {
         browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(element(by.id('text'))), 15000);    
         expect(element(by.id('text')).getText()).toEqual('Works');
         expect(element(by.css('#crumbsNav .last')).getText()).toEqual('Payment');
     });
     browser.driver.close();
     browser.driver.switchTo().window(handles[0]);
});
```

Comment: browser.wait(function(){return handles.size() > 1}, 15000); // It is not like this?

Comment: With that code, always opens two tabs and shows the error "UnknownError: null value in entry: name=null". I say it opens two tabs because the spec consists in test four links that open new tab. So I repeat that code with diffent elements, with four links.